# AEM 6.2: Submit/Save adaptive form to a shared folder

Tags: java, forms, aem, jcr

I am new to AEM and working on this functionality where I am trying to save the adaptive form to an external shared folder.

Currently the submit action stores all the submitted forms on CRX as nodes.

Instead of this, i am looking for a way to save the filled form in a work folder, say `W://StoreFolder/Forms/*`.

Any input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a workflow/process for your submission? 
If so, in the workbench you can use the activity Foundation -> FileUtilsService -> Write Document

You can specify a pathname on the local file system e.g.
c:\aemforms_output\test.pdf

And set the document to your pdf document variable.

Works for me!